# How to Enable clickable Action in the multicolumn ListView?

Tags: android

How to Enable clickable Action in the multicolumn ListView? if I am using the EditText inside the multi Column custom listView, but I can't able to select the listView items.Because the list items are not clickable.if I don't use the EditText means, I can click the list items. But if I used EditText inside the custom listview then itemClick is not allowed.

```
      public class TicketActivity extends Activity{
TextView t1;
TextView t2;
ListView l1;
TextView t6;
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ticket);
t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   //Get the Table no Value From Edit Text


Intent i1=getIntent();
Bundle b=i1.getExtras();
int num=b.getInt("Table No:");
    String pno=Integer.toString(num);
    t1.setText(pno);

        //Get The Guest Value From Edit Text

    Intent i2=getIntent();
    Bundle b1=i2.getExtras();
    int num1=b1.getInt("Guest:");
    String pno1=Integer.toString(num1);
    t2.setText(pno1);


   // List<String> st=GlobalClass.myval;

      //ArrayAdapter<String> ada = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,st);

    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(TicketActivity.this));

         l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){


       String[] s1 = (String[]) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected:"+ s1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   });

   } 
   private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;



    public EfficientAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // implementation of EfficientAdapter   
    }
    public int getCount() {

        return GlobalClass.myval.size();

    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position ;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        String[] stockArr = new String[GlobalClass.myval.size()];
        stockArr = GlobalClass.myval.toArray(stockArr);
        String[] stockArr1=new String[GlobalClass.myvals.size()];
        stockArr1=GlobalClass.myvals.toArray(stockArr1);
    if(convertView==null){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ticket, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.Text1=(EditText)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            holder.Text2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.Text3=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
              holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
           holder.Text1.setText("1");
            holder.Text2.setText(stockArr[position]);
            holder.Text3.setText(stockArr1[position]);
            return convertView;

     }

    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        EditText Text1;
        TextView Text2;
        TextView Text3;

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setOnItemClickListener() for your listview.You can use it in following manner.

```
l1.setOnItemClickListener(yourListener);

private OnItemClickListener yourListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    private String getSelectedItemOfList;

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View view1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getSelectedItemOfList = yourlist.get(pos).toString; // Here you can get selected item of listview.
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.Let me know is it works or not?